# Redirect vBulletin URLs to XenForo with NGINX rewrite rules

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, redirect, ngx-http-rewrite-module

I would like to know how to rewrite the nginx this url:

Old URL: http://www.webcheats.com.br/vbulletin/showthread.php?t=2175433

New URL: http://www.webcheats.com.br/threads/2175433/

thanks

Comment: You'll have to hardcode that

Comment: @MarcosBianchi, congratulations, you now have a rep of 15, and you can upvote my answer, too. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
location = /vbulletin/showthread.php {
    return 301 /threads/$arg_t/;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Xenforo 2 on nginx and you had previously migrated from vBulletin there is an addon for Xenforo 2 that handles the redirects:
[Xenforo Redirects for vBulletin](https://xenforo.com/community/resources/xenforo-redirects-for-vbulletin.6123/)

But this addon was made for Apache, and out of the box it won't work correctly with the SEO friendly URL feature of Xenforo 2 & nginx.  To resolve that issue you need to setup your nginx config to work with SEO friendly URLS using the [XF2 Documentation](https://xenforo.com/xf2-docs/manual/options/#friendly-urls).

Last thing you need to do is read [this post](https://xenforo.com/community/threads/xenforo-redirects-for-vbulletin.142137/post-1370876) which outlines the cause of the issue and the fix.  The cause of the problem is this line:

```
  try_files $uri =404;
```

It stops the redirect from occuring because the old vbulletin php files don't exist.  The final fix is to set the block to look like this:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
  try_files $uri /index.php?$uri&$args;
  #try_files $uri =404;
  fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
  fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  include         fastcgi_params;
}
```